# What's wrong with "~" key?

Tags: 3d-view

[image]
Sometimes when I press "~" key, the view panel doesn't appear, and I get no any reaction, why and how can I fix it, thanks!

[image]

Comment: What's your expectation? What should happen when you press it? If you hover your mouse over 3D viewport it should give you View pie menu(with Blender's default "Factory" settings), but if you hover over Properties Editor for example it's not supposed to do anything...

Comment: I update my post, actually it always shows the view panel, but sometimes it doesn't work, thanks for you comment

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. It always works for me. I suspect your mouse may sometimes be in the wrong part of the UI. All Blender hot keys are context dependant and most of them depend on what part of UI the mouse is over.

Comment: are you sure your `~` key is perfectly functional? open notepad and test see if it works 100% of the time.